# Grails UnitTest Ensure BigDecimal not a string

Tags: java, grails, groovy

System:
Java 1.7
Grails 2.2

In my Domain Object:

```
class Timer{

    BigDecimal hours

    static constraints = {
        hours min: 0.5, validator: { h ->
            // The hours has to be a number in whole or half hour increments.

               System.out.println "h:" + h.toString()

            // Twice the number :
            def h2 = 2 * h

            // Extract h2 fractional portion:
            String numberStr = Double.toString(h2);
            String fractionalStr = numberStr.substring(numberStr.indexOf('.') + 1);
            int fractional = Integer.valueOf(fractionalStr);

            System.out.println "fraction:" + fractional

            // if the fraction is 0 then "h" is a multiple of 0.5
            // ie: h = 1.5 => h2 = 3.0, fractional = 0  return TRUE
            // ie: h = 1.1 => h2 = 2.2, fractional = 2  return FALSE
            (fractional == 0)
        }
    }
}
```

In the Unit Test

```
@Build(Timer)
class TimerTests {


    @Before
    void setUp() {

        // Ensure we can invoke validate() on our domain object.
        mockForConstraintsTests(Timer)
    }

    /**
     * Ensure setup creates a valid instance
     */
    void testValid() {
        Timer t = Timer.build()
        assertTrue t.validate()
    }


    /**
     * hours must be a number
     */
    void testHours(){
        Timer m = Timer.build()
        assertTrue m.validate()



        t.hours = 1;
        assertTrue m.validate()

        t.hours = 1.5;
        assertTrue m.validate()

        t.hours = 1.3;
        assertFalse m.validate()
        assertEquals 'validator', t.errors['hours']

        // Test Min constraint
        t.hours = 0;
        assertFalse t.validate()
        assertEquals 'min', t.errors['hours']


        //
        // Test non numbers
        t = new Timer()
        t.hours = "ss"
        assertFalse t.validate()
    }
}
```

I get the error org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'ss' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.math.BigDecimal'

I want to ensure that a string cannot be entered, and the hours field is in whole or half hour increments.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Your test shows it can't be a string.  You need to change your code to expect an Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following:

```
t.hours = "ss"
```

You are assigning a `String` value to a property of type `BigDecimal`.

If you let the data binding system do the assignment then you get to take advantage of a bunch of functionality that you are circumventing by assigning a value directly to the property.

The following test will pass (I left the `.build()` stuff out of the mix for simplicity):

```
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

@TestFor(Timer)
class TimerTests {

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        // Ensure we can invoke validate() on our domain object.
        mockForConstraintsTests(Timer)
    }

    void testHours(){
        Timer m = new Timer(hours: 1)
        assertTrue m.validate()

        m.hours = 1.5;
        assertTrue m.validate()

        m.hours = 1.3;
        assertFalse m.validate()
        assertEquals 'validator', m.errors['hours']

        // Test Min constraint
        m.hours = 0;
        assertFalse m.validate()
        assertEquals 'min', m.errors['hours']

        // Test non numbers
        m = new Timer(hours: 'ss')
        assertFalse m.validate()
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The original question doesn't specify which 2.2.x release is being used.  I tested that with Grails 2.2.5.

Comment: The test isn't addressing this but the last call to `.validate()` should return false because `hours` is null.  `hours` will be null because of a type conversion error.  If you interrogate `m.errors` before calling `.validate()`, the binding error should be present.

Comment: Wow that was a quick and fantastic response.  It works perfectly.  Also you are correct assertEquals 'nullable', m.errors['hours'] should be the last line instead of what I wrote.  Thank you.